# Error (Xcode): unable to attach DB: error: accessing build database(Flutter)

Tags: xcode, flutter

Every time I run my Flutter Project which is connected to Firebase this error appears.

I've tried:

- flutter clean
- flutter build iOS

But nothing worked.

This is my pubspec.yaml

```
name: pay_app
description: A new Flutter project.


publish_to: 'none' 

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^1.16.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.17
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.14
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: Facing same issue for me also, do you find any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue in react native and solved this by doing following things, let's give it a try may be it can work for you guys too!

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
pod deintegrate
pod update
```